# devise_token_auth: Why is my POST curl not returning uid/client id/token?

Tags: authentication, curl, post, devise, jwt

I have followed all of the instructions for setting up devise token auth in my rails app, but first I am trying to test the auth system with curl, so that I know the proper parameters to include in my react fetch code.

Using the official docs for devise token auth, along with another stackoverflow post (which showed registration but not login), I was able to figure out how to register a user with curl. Registering with curl returned the uid, client id, and access token, but according to the docs, logging in is supposed to return these values as well, and I need to be able to store them for session control.

This is my curl (`myserver.com`, and `myphonenumber` are placeholders for the actual url and phone number)

`curl -POST -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://myserver.com/auth/sign_in -d '{"email": "test@test.com", "password": "rabbit"}'`

which returns the following response:

```
> POST /auth/sign_in HTTP/1.1
> Host: myserver.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 54
>
* upload completely sent off: 54 out of 54 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Tue, 08 May 2018 04:47:02 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< ETag: W/"54281896f954d99dcd6989e8e82e7d79"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< X-Request-Id: 1f619b39-87d4-44f4-9990-c0804a2a0a74
< X-Runtime: 0.311010
< Front-End-Https: on
<
* Connection #0 to host myserver.com left intact
{"data":{"id":12,"email":"test@test.com","provider":"phone","uid":"test@test.com","name":null,"image":null,"phone_number":"myphonenumber"}}
```

I feel like my POST might be missing headers or something... but the output it's giving me isn't giving much of a clue. I know name and image are marked as null, but from what I read in the docs, it doesn't seem like they are necessary. Also, it usually gave me a 400 bad request if I was missing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel like my POST might be missing headers or something.

This *IS* your HTTP post request header:

```
> POST /auth/sign_in HTTP/1.1
> Host: myserver.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 54
```

And this is the returned JSON:

```
{"data":{"id":12,"email":"test@test.com","provider":"phone","uid":"test@test.com","name":null,"image":null,"phone_number":"myphonenumber"}}
```

Comment: I know, but the header is supposed return more values.  When I use curl to register it returns uid, client id and an access token. The devise token auth docs also say that it should return these values on sign in as well, but it's not. I need these values so I can save them to persist sessions. Content type is specified as a header in the POST curl, I figured maybe I need to include something for the access token too, but I'm not sure what to include.

Comment: If you can do it in a Browser, use the Browser's developers tool's Network tab to get exactly what was posted and what was returned.  I sometimes copy the entire request header from the browser and add it all to the curl request.  I am not that familiar with command line curl, I generally use PHP.

Comment: This is for a mobile app though, and I'm making the request through the terminal right now purely for test purposes. Thing is, it doesn't matter whether or not I can see the results in a browser, I'm just testing it right now. It needs to be accessible to my app so that I can store the token for future logins.